# iOS Twitter API; How to retrieve the most recent tweets within a country?

Tags: ios, twitter, frameworks, local, tweets

I am new to the Twitter API and iOS, but reading the documentation I learned to use the "Twitter.framework" in xCode and the "TWRequest" class in specific.

The most obvious way to go would be to make a request to:

```
GET statuses/public_timeline
```

However that request does not allow a parameter to specify a latitude and a longitude to get the most recent public tweets within a country. I did find:

```
GET geo/search
```

Which allows me to set all kind of cool parameters such as lat, long and granularity, but unfortunately it does not return tweets in the results.

So is it possible? Or a lost cost?

---

**Edit:**

So I guess I should be using:

```
GET search
```

But the only downfall is that I should give a q (query), a search term, but I am not searching for a specific term. I just like to retrieve the most recent public tweets in a given country. So is there, and should I use, a wildcard?

Comment: Please add the answer as an actual answer to the post and mark it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a request to:

```
GET geo/search
```

To get the place ID. For `The Netherlands` the ID is `879d7cfc66c9c290`.

Then make a search request to:

```
GET search
```

With the query:

```
q=place:{PLACE_ID}
```

*Example: "q=place:879d7cfc66c9c290"*

If you like to get the most recent you can also set a parameter called `result_type` and set it to `recent` and that's it. Hope it helps people.