# How can we get tweets from specific country

Tags: python, twitter, geocoding, tweets, country

I've read a lot about this part and what I found is to write the geocode and search for tweets
for example
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi&count=10

according to what i found in twitter website
Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given latitude/longitude. 
A maximum of 1,000 distinct "sub-regions" will be considered when using the radius modifier.
Example Values: 37.781157,-122.398720,1mi

The question!, how can we define or draw the latitude and longitude ? I've tried google map but I only get a point then i can add the miles around this point, but this is not enough, I want the whole country to be included, is that possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way is to use twitter [geo search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/search), get the place id and then perform regular search using `place:place_id`. Example, using [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy):

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(..., ...)
auth.set_access_token(..., ...)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
places = api.geo_search(query="USA", granularity="country")
place_id = places[0].id

tweets = api.search(q="place:%s" % place_id)
for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet.text + " | " + tweet.place.name if tweet.place else "Undefined place"
```

Also see these threads:

- [iOS Twitter API; How to retrieve the most recent tweets within a country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140235/ios-twitter-api-how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-tweets-within-a-country)
- [How do I get top tweeps by country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649679/how-do-i-get-top-tweeps-by-country)

UPD (the same example using python-twitter):

```
from twitter import *


t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(..., ..., ..., ...))

result = t.geo.search(query="USA", granularity="country")
place_id = result['result']['places'][0]['id']

result = t.search.tweets(q="place:%s" % place_id)
for tweet in result['statuses']:
    print tweet['text'] + " | " + tweet['place']['name'] if tweet['place'] else "Undefined place"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing but with python-twitter wrapper ?

Comment: Sure, I've added an example. Please, check.

Comment: How would you include query for a specific set of hashtags in the above code?

Comment: Is this also doable for the stream API?

Comment: @HammanSamuel unfortunately, it's being a while I've used twitter API, please try searching through SO. If there is not a question about it, don't hesistate to ask. Thanks!

Comment: This will return tweets about a country. And not tweets from a country right?

Comment: @alecxe I am also doing something like this, so tell me What is the value of place_id?

Comment: link for `geo search API` is broken as of 20181206

Comment: For some countries it does not work correclty. If I try United Kingdom or France it returns United States and Franch Guiana