# Twitter Api using geocode how to select the whole country UK?

Tags: php, twitter

I am searching for tweets within the UK ONLY, how to I search using geo code?

```
$results = $twitter->search(array('q' => 'my search', 'geocode' => 'xxxx,yyyy,zzzzkm'));
```

What do I put for xxxx, yyyy and zzzz ?

Is it possible to search by country not geocode?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) geocode parameter:

> Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given
>   latitude/longitude. The location is preferentially taking from the
>   Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The
>   parameter value is specified by “**latitude,longitude,radius**”, where
>   radius units must be specified as either “mi” (miles) or “km”
>   (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API
>   to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode
>   parameter to search near geocodes directly. A maximum of 1,000
>   distinct “sub-regions” will be considered when using the radius
>   modifier.

```
Example Values: 37.781157,-122.398720,1mi
```

If you want to search for country take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633378/how-can-we-get-tweets-from-specific-country).

Comment: How to I search for whole UK using place? country_code ? GB?

Comment: $results = $twitter->search(array('q' => 'car', 'place' => array('country_code' => 'GB') ) );   this does not work??

Answer (score 0):

Search Twitter by country:

```
$results = $twitter->search(array('q' => 'my search', 'place' => array('country' => 'United Kingdom') ) );
```