# R: How can I get just geocoded American tweets

Tags: r, twitter

I understand that the only way to ensure getting geocoded tweets using the twitteR package is by specifying a geocode. However, apparently, even if you specify a wide range (e.g., 3000 miles) priority is given to tweets near the center of the range. 
e.g.:

```
tweets<-searchTwitter('s',  n=2000, geocode='37.000,-120.00,3000mi')
```

gives you mainly California and Arizona tweets. I don't see that feature/bug documented anywhere, but was a pretty robust finding when I tried lots of different spots (e.g., specifying the middle of the US gave mostly IL/AR tweets).

Is there any way around this to get mostly American geocoded tweets?
I'm happy to do some filtering, but given the time to get tweets, I don't want to have to filter out 95% of the data.

Comment: Nice. The Twitter API actually supports it (Similar ques in [python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633378/how-can-we-get-tweets-from-specific-country)). I went through the docs of `twitterR` again. Interestingly they just give the trends of a country. Hopefully someone may be able to answer your question :)