# How to extract tweets location which contain specific keyword using twitter API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tweepy

I am trying to extract the all tweets which contain specific keyword and its geo locations .

for example , I want download all the tweets in english which contains the keyword **'iphone'**  from **'france'** and **'singapore'**

**My code**

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys

# API credentials here
consumer_key = 'INSERT CONSUMER KEY HERE'
consumer_secret = 'INSERT CONSUMER SECRET HERE'
access_token = 'INSERT ACCESS TOKEN HERE'
access_token_secret = 'INSERT ACCESS TOKEN SECRET HERE'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# Search word/hashtag value 
HashValue = ""

# search start date value. the search will start from this date to the current date.
StartDate = ""

# getting the search word/hashtag and date range from user
HashValue = input("Enter the hashtag you want the tweets to be downloaded for: ")
StartDate = input("Enter the start date in this format yyyy-mm-dd: ")

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open(HashValue+'.csv', 'a')

#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=HashValue,count=20,lang="en",since=StartDate, tweet_mode='extended').items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])

print ("Scraping finished and saved to "+HashValue+".csv")
#sys.exit()
```

How can this be done.

Comment: Did you try the solution given in this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633378/how-can-we-get-tweets-from-specific-country

Comment: @RegiMathew, thats tells about extracting tweets from a particular location. My question is about which location is the tweet coming from

Comment: Are you open to solutions that use other methods/libraries? Or must it be in tweepy only

Comment: @Zulfiqaar, Yes . I am open to other methods

Comment: try the twitterscraper module, query_tweets is what i use usually

Answer (score 1):

-Hello- Rahul

As I understand it you are looking to get geo data off searched tweets rather then filter search based on geocode.

Here is a code sample with the relevant fields you are interested in. These may or may not be provided depending on the tweeters privacy settings.

Note there is no "since" parameter on the search API:

https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#help-methods

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

Standard twitter api search goes back 7 days. The premium and enterprise APIs have 30 day search as well as Full Archive search, but you will pay $$$.

Unfortunately tweepy still hasn't had their models documented:

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/720

So if you want to look at the tweet object you can use pprint package and run:

```
pprint(tweet.__dict__)
```

One difference I noticed was the "text" field in the JSON became "full_text" in the object.

There's also information on the original tweet in there if the one you found was a quote tweet, has the same info from what I could see.

Anyway here's the code, I added a max tweet count for looping through the cursor while I was testing to avoid blowing any API limits.

Let me know if you want csv code but it looks like you can handle that already.

```
import tweepy

# API credentials here
consumer_key = 'your-info'
consumer_secret = 'your-info'
access_token = 'your-info'
access_token_secret = 'your-info'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

searchString = "iPhone"

cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchString, count=20, lang="en", tweet_mode='extended')

maxCount = 1
count = 0
for tweet in cursor.items():    
    print()
    print("Tweet Information")
    print("================================")
    print("Text: ", tweet.full_text)
    print("Geo: ", tweet.geo)
    print("Coordinates: ", tweet.coordinates)
    print("Place: ", tweet.place)
    print()

    print("User Information")
    print("================================")
    print("Location: ", tweet.user.location)
    print("Geo Enabled? ", tweet.user.geo_enabled)

    count = count + 1
    if count == maxCount:
        break;
```

Will output something like this:

```
Tweet Information
================================
Text:  NowPlaying : Hashfinger - Leaving
https://derp.com

#iPhone free app https://derp.com
#peripouwebradio
Geo:  None
Coordinates:  None
Place:  None

User Information
================================
Location:  Greece
Geo Enabled?  True
```